# How can I alter the value returned from a hook?

Tags: hooks

I installed the [Two-factor Authentication (TFA)](https://www.drupal.org/project/tfa) and the [TFA Basic plugins](https://ttps://www.drupal.org/project/tfa_basic) modules.

I want to alter the value returned from [`tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/tfa_basic/-/blob/7.x-1.x/tfa_basic.module#L279), which is a hook implementation, in a custom module.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_tfa_ready_require().
 */
function tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require($account) {
  if (tfa_basic_tfa_required($account)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Login disallowed. You are required to set up two-factor authentication. Please contact a site administrator.'), 'error');
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

I tried the following code in the custom_tfa.module file, but it does not work.

```php
function custom_tfa_tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require_alter($account) {
  drupal_set_message(t('TEST'), 'warning');
  return FALSE;
}
```

How can I alter the value returned from a hook?

Comment: If the hook is named `hook_tfa_ready_require` and your custom module is named `custom_tfa` then your custom module needs to implement `custom_tfa_tfa_ready_require($account)`.

Comment: Hi leymannx, but that was the Drupal 7 module of tfa_basic, which is included with tfa (main module). I was thinking whether able to alter the methods inside the tfa_basic only. hook_tfa_ready_require() is from the tfa module though, how do I determine which of their methods is a hook?

Comment: Alter hooks are not supposed to return any value. They get a parameter passed by reference; they just need to alter it.

Comment: To understand which functions are hook implementations, it is sufficient to look at the documentation comment for that function: `Implements hook_tfa_ready_require().` says that is a hook implementation.

Comment: So there is no way to change the method tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require from the tfa_basic module?

Comment: `how do I determine which of their methods is a hook?` Read the code [block comment](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/tfa_basic/-/blob/7.x-1.x/tfa_basic.module#L277). `So there is no way to change the method tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require from the tfa_basic module?` No, you would create your custom module and implement the hook function there. In other words, just do what leymannx said, m'kay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require()` shows a message when it returns `TRUE`, altering the value returned from that hook is not sufficient. It would not make sense to show *Login disallowed. You are required to set up two-factor authentication. Please contact a site administrator.* when the login is allowed.

To avoid Drupal core invokes `tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require()`, it is necessary to implement [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x).

```php
function custom_tfa_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'tfa_ready_require') {
    unset($implementations['tfa_basic']);
  }
}
```

Then, the module can implement its own `hook_tfa_ready_require()`.

```php
function custom_tfa_tfa_ready_require($account) {
  return FALSE;
}
```

As a side note, `custom_tfa_tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require_alter()` would eventually be an alter hook implemented by the *custom_tfa* module for the `hook_tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require()` hook implementations. Leaving out the fact alter hooks get different parameters, `hook_tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require()` is not the hook implemented from `tfa_basic_tfa_ready_require()`.

As a further note, alter hooks are invoked when the module that uses them calls `drupal_alter()`. Usually, for `hook_HOOK_TYPE()`, `hook_HOOK_TYPE_alter()` is invoked too; that is not always the case, though. In the cases where `hook_HOOK_TYPE()` is invoked, but `hook_HOOK_TYPE_alter()` is **not** invoked, implementing `hook_module_implements_alter()` is the solution, although it requires to duplicate code from the other module and to keep the new hook implementation updated each time the other module's hook is updated.