# TFA Session expired when user login

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization, sessions

not sure if anyone faces this issue, when I tried to login with the authentication. It shows TFA session has expired. But the user account was logged in. Screenshot attached, I tried to drupal set message instead of dpm(), notice that the expires property was gone.

Screenshot 1 - authentication verification
[image: Screenshot 1 - authentication verification]

Screenshot 2 - TFA session expired message but the user was logged in
[image: Screenshot 2 - TFA session expired message but the user was logged in]

My Drupal version: 7.87
PHP version: 7.032

Steps to produce issue:

1. Install tfa_basic-7.x-1.2.zip module
2. Install tfa-7.x-2.3.zip module
3. Login as Administrator and assign authentication to user
4. Open Incognito browser, user logins in and verify the authentication
5. TFA Session expired from Drupal_set_message

Comment: Have you altered (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/316712/how-can-i-alter-the-value-returned-from-a-hook) or patched the module?

Comment: Also please add the Drupal + module version.

Comment: Actually, the `expire` value is higher than `REQUEST_TIME`: for example, 1692763073 versus 1692762773.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to show text. Screenshots are not indexed and they cannot copy-pasted.

Comment: @PatrickKenny sorry, just added my Drupal and php versions. As well as the steps to produce.

Comment: @cilefen I never alter or patch the modules, purely used the modules released from TFA (tfa-7.x-2.3) and TFA_basic (tfa_basic-7.x-1.2) for my server's Drupal 7.87